# My Website sidebar messed up on browser resize

Tags: sidebar, overlapping

My website sidebar overlaps with the main content area on browser resize.

When viewed at 100% in Google Chrome

[image]

When viewed at 80% zoom

[image]

This is my website http://www.phebestephen.com/the-path-to-promise/ 
I am new to css and have very little idea on how to fix it. Please help!
Thank you

Comment: Can you show what you have written ?

Comment: .site-main .sidebar-container {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.site-main .widget-area {
 float: right;
 width: 300px;
}